# Proving that the absolute value function is elementary.

Tags: calculus, continuity, absolute-value, elementary-functions

My proof is:

The absolute value function f is defined as x when $x\geq 0 $, hence it is a polynomail hence elementary function and it is defined as -x when $x < 0$ hence it is also a polynomial and hence elementary function, is my proof correct?

Comment: What's "elementary"?

Comment: my book consider the polynomials elementary functions @Arthur

Comment: Is it the same as this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function ?

Comment: For me it feels like it's possible (and even easy) to obtain the absolute value of a number with a finite number of arithmetic operations, namely only by multiplying it by $1$ or $-1$. Is there something more than this, I wonder ...?

Comment: My book author is  John Petrovic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Piecewise functions are not elementary functions in general.

The absolute value can be expressed as

$$|x| = \sqrt{(x^2)}$$

which is elementary, being a composition of a polynomial root and a polynomial.

Comment: Is the polynomial root an elementary function?

Comment: Yes, by the definition in the Wiki link above. If you don't know the definition, you shouldn't be trying to prove things about it. ;)

Comment: My book say only that power functions are elementary (not root polynomials) @mr_e_man

Comment: Only power functions? What about sums of powers? or exponential or trigonometric functions? or rational functions? Anyway, you should provide the definitions in the question at first, so people know how to answer properly.

Comment: @hopefully: What about the power 1/2 then?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which concept of “elementary function” you are using, but I doubt that it allows you to deduce that if a function has several branches and it is elementary in each one of them, then it is elementary.

On the other hand, you can probably prove that the absolute function is elementary using the fact that$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\lvert x\rvert=\sqrt{x^2}.$$